# How to alert contents of console.log?

Tags: javascript, alert, prompt, console.log

I would like to alert/prompt the contents of `console.log()`.

How to alert/prompt - `console.log("I want to eat" + " " + food);`?
I tried `alert("I want to eat" + " " + food);` but it does not seem to be valid.

e.g.

```
<script>
var foodDemand = function(food) {

  console.log("I want to eat" + " " + food);

};

foodDemand("Fried Chicken");
</script>
```

How to alert/prompt - `console.log("I want to eat" + " " + food);`?
I tried `alert("I want to eat" + " " + food);` but it does not seem to be valid.

`foodDemand("Fried Chicken");` yields in the console:
`"I want to eat Fried Chicken"`

How can i get the same with `prompt();` or `alert();`?

Comment: change `console.log` to `alert` or `prompt` and it does work as expected.

Comment: exactly as you did... , replace `console.log` with `alert` and that's it...

Comment: To be pedantic, I'd change the string a little bit too: `alert("I want to eat " + food);`

Comment: @Andy Or just you single quotes: `alert('I want to eat ' + food);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   its working for me

 <script>
    var foodDemand = function(food) {

      alert(food);

    };

    foodDemand("Fried Chicken");
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work without any problems, as I can demonstrate with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrXVU/)

note that you do not need to add the space separately, do it like this:

`"I want to eat " + food`